# virtual scroll for version 5.2.0

Tags: angular, virtualscroll

I have a simple question, is there a way to perform virtual scroll for angular with angular/cdk version 5.2.0

Because i get the error : src/app/app.module.ts(67,10): error TS2305: Module node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling"' has no exported member 'ScrollingModule'.

Thanks you for any help !

Comment: No, virtual scrolling with the ScrollingModule was added in version 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

No Virtual Scrolling was added in later version(7.0.0) . still you can use paging and infinite scrolling in this version .